# TypeError when I try to implement a function on a grid

Tags: python, function, numpy, typeerror

### Introduction

I have a pair of functions called numerical(x,y,z) and analytic(x,y,z), where numerical(x,y,z) is an approximation to analytic(x,y,z). I want to make some contour plots to see how these functions look in the x-y plane, so for the functions below I have set z=0. I have then tried to define the functions on a grid;

```
def numerical_plane(x,y):
    return numerical(x, y, 0)

def analytic_plane(x,y):
    R = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
    return -G*M/(np.sqrt(R**2 + (a+np.sqrt(b**2))**2))

x = np.linspace(-20, 20, 50)
y = np.linspace(-20, 20, 50)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = numerical(X, Y)
Z2 = analytic(X, Y)
```

the function numerical(x,y,z) is defined at the bottom of this question.

### Issue

Z2 works fine, but Z1 raises

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

As this is a TypeError, I tried checking the type returned by numerical(1,2); it was  a float. analytic(1,2) on the other hand returns a numpy.float64. I tried forcing numerical(x,y) to return a numpy.float64 but this didn't actually help, so maybe I'm on the wrong track. Does anyone understand what's going wrong here?

If you need **more information about the function numerical(x,y,z)**, then I've written it's definition here

```
def rho(x,y,z,M = 5e10,a = 4,b =0.8):

    R = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
    rho = ((b**2*M)/(4*np.pi))*(a*R**2+(a+3*np.sqrt(z**2+b**2))*(a+np.sqrt(z**2+b**2))**2)\
          /((R**2+(a+np.sqrt(z**2+b**2))**2)**(2.5)*(z**2+b**2)**(1.5))
    return rho

def numerical(x, y, z, s=0.01):

    integrand = lambda xx, yy, zz: -G*rho(xx,yy,zz,M,a,b)/(np.sqrt((xx-      x)**2+(yy-y)**2+(zz-z)**2+s**2))      
    phi =   nquad(integrand, ranges = [(-np.inf, np.inf), (-np.inf, np.inf), (-np.inf, np.inf)], opts = {'epsrel' : 1e-1})[0]
    return phi
```

It involves calling another function rho(x,y,z, ...), and then performing an integration over all space.

Here is also the full-traceback ...

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-cb38a0d34db9> in <module>()
     11 X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
     12 Z1 = analytic(X, Y)
---> 13 Z2 = numeric(X, Y)

<ipython-input-62-cb38a0d34db9> in numeric(x, y)
      1 def numeric(x,y):
----> 2     return numerical_phi_MN(x, y, 0)
      3 
      4 def analytic(x,y):
      5     R = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)

<ipython-input-43-c7e02143837e> in numerical_phi_MN(x, y, z, s)
     14 
     15     integrand = lambda xx, yy, zz: -G*rho_MN(xx,yy,zz,M,a,b)/(np.sqrt((xx-x)**2+(yy-y)**2+(zz-z)**2+s**2))
---> 16     phi =   nquad(integrand, ranges = [(-np.inf, np.inf), (-np.inf, np.inf), (-np.inf, np.inf)], opts = {'epsrel' : 1e-1})[0]
     17 
     18     return phi

/opt/python-2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.pyc in nquad(func, ranges, args, opts, full_output)
    712     else:
    713         opts = [opt if callable(opt) else _OptFunc(opt) for opt in opts]
--> 714     return _NQuad(func, ranges, opts, full_output).integrate(*args)
    715 
    716 

/opt/python-2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.pyc in integrate(self, *args, **kwargs)
    767             f = partial(self.integrate, depth=depth+1)
    768         quad_r = quad(f, low, high, args=args, full_output=self.full_output,
--> 769                       **opt)
    770         value = quad_r[0]
    771         abserr = quad_r[1]

/opt/python-2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.pyc in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst)
    321     if (weight is None):
    322         retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
--> 323                        points)
    324     else:
    325         retval = _quad_weight(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel,

/opt/python-2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.pyc in _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points)
    388             return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    389         else:
--> 390             return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    391     else:
    392         if infbounds != 0:

/opt/python-2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.pyc in integrate(self, *args, **kwargs)
    767             f = partial(self.integrate, depth=depth+1)
    768         quad_r = quad(f, low, high, args=args, full_output=self.full_output,
--> 769                       **opt)
    770         value = quad_r[0]
    771         abserr = quad_r[1]

/opt/python-2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.pyc in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst)
    321     if (weight is None):
    322         retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
--> 323                        points)
    324     else:
    325         retval = _quad_weight(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel,

/opt/python-2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.pyc in _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points)
    388             return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    389         else:
--> 390             return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    391     else:
    392         if infbounds != 0:

/opt/python-2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.pyc in integrate(self, *args, **kwargs)
    767             f = partial(self.integrate, depth=depth+1)
    768         quad_r = quad(f, low, high, args=args, full_output=self.full_output,
--> 769                       **opt)
    770         value = quad_r[0]
    771         abserr = quad_r[1]

/opt/python-2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.pyc in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst)
    321     if (weight is None):
    322         retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
--> 323                        points)
    324     else:
    325         retval = _quad_weight(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel,

/opt/python-2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.pyc in _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points)
    388             return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    389         else:
--> 390             return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    391     else:
    392         if infbounds != 0:

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Many thanks

Comment: Please provide the full traceback so we know at what line this issue occurs.

Comment: Currently `G`, `M`, `rrho_MN` are not defined. The first two are obviously numerical constants, but the latter is a function...

Comment: Apologies @Graphier... the names of the functions in my working code are quite messy, so in an attempt to make my code more readable, as I transferred my code into stackoverflow, I gave my functions simpler names. For example, 'numerical(x,y,z)' in my question is actually 'numerical_phi_MN(x,y,z)' in my code. I deleted the subscript  '_phi_MN' to make the name shorter. I did a similar thing for 'rho', but as you noticed I forgot to remove the subscript in all cases. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`scipy.integrate.nquad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html) can only integrate a single (n-dimensional) function. Therefore it will always return a single value, instead of applying to a multidimensional vector element-wise.

You can get around this by making the function vectorized, using [`numpy.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html). However, note what is being said in the documentation:

> The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for
>   performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

With this (and `G = 1`, `M = 1`, `rho_MN = rho`), it runs (albeit taking a long time, will let you know when it finishes):

```
def numerical_plane(x, y):
    return np.vectorize(numerical)(x, y, 0)
```